# TabularInlines readonly fields are deleteable

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using `TabularInlines` for administrate many-to-many relationships in the django admin. When some conditions are met, I want to make the inline read only. To achieve this I override the `get_readonly_fields()` method from the `BaseModelAdmin`.

This works like a charm, with the only problem, that the read only fields are still deleteable (the checkbox for the deletion is still there and still works).

Of course I could set the `can_delete` field in the `TabularInline` to `False` but this prevents the deletion also for not read only cases.

My question: How can I set up the `TabularInline` that I can prohibit the deletion in read only fields and enable it if the fields are read/writeable?

**EDIT:** I use Django 1.3, but if the solution also works for 1.2 it would be perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is set `has_delete_permission(self, obj=None)`.  That will allow you to decide when you can and cannot delete an entire inline.